# why service is stopping

Tags: android, audio, android-service

I am creating service to play sound in my app. Audio start when app start with splash screen then main menu activity start. Main menu activity have 4 buttons. I am not stopping my service on click on any button (you can see in my code) but when I run my app on my device on click on any button service stop and when I came back from next activity to this one. Sound again start. I want to finish service sound on last activity of the app.

Code of main menu activity-

```
private Button hist, typ, ben, exit;
    Intent i, objIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton()
    {
        hist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hist);
        hist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, History.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        typ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.typ);
        typ.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Types.class));  
                finish();        
            }
        });

        ben = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ben);
        ben.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Benefits.class));  
                finish();               
            }
        });

        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EndSplash.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        objIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayAudio.class);
        stopService(objIntent);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        objIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayAudio.class);
        stopService(objIntent);         
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        objIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayAudio.class);
        startService(objIntent);
    }
}
```

SplashScreen Activity-

```
TimerTask task;
    Intent objIntent, intent;
    Handler handler; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.splash);
       UtilClass.playing = true;
       objIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, PlayAudio.class);
       startService(objIntent);
       new Handler().postDelayed(csRunnable2, 5000);  
       }

   Runnable csRunnable2 = new Runnable() 
    {      
       @Override
       public void run() 
       {
            intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
       }
   };

   public void onBackPressed()  
    {    
      //  myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
        objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayAudio.class);
        stopService(objIntent);
        finish();
        return;  
    }  

   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayAudio.class);
        stopService(objIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you will navigate to another activity, your Current's Activity's `onPause` will be called and you are already stopping the service in your `onPause` method.

You also need to comment the code that is stopping your service in the `onPause` Method :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //objIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayAudio.class);
    //stopService(objIntent);
}
```

You can also post your Service's code for more appropriate answer, thanks.

Comment: I am starting service in splash screen and at the time of starting this activity I am finish() that I dont think finish have any affect on this. Wait I update my question.

Comment: What about the onPause method ??

Comment: In splash screen I have finish(). onReume() and onPause() method But still audio is playing in menu activity.

Comment: What is the total length of your SOund file ?

Comment: One new problem its playing on click on last 3 buttons not on first button.

Answer (score 0):

please check activity life cycle http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Onpause() and onResume() will call when your moving from one activity to another activity. in your code your starting and stopping service in   Onpause() and onResume().